# Export configurable products with ASSOCIATED Column

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

This is driving me crazy. No matter what export I do using profile, the column "assocciated", as mentioned in various magento guides is missing. I have around 7000 products and need to export them with the parent/child relationship intact, however, after export it just shows all the products without any columns mentioning the relationship also link for only 1 image is shown even when there are more than 5 images.

I would like to see the configurable products with all the associated products (seperated by comma) OR simple products with the sku of configurable product. 
Is there any option to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

U can use this code
 (please make filename.php under your web root

```
<?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();

//$parentProduct= Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load('2862');
$parentCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id','configurable')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('status','1');
            //$pid = array();
$read= Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
function getAttributeValue($value){
    global $read;
    $query = "select value from eav_attribute_option_value where option_id = '$value'";
    $customAttributeValue = $read->fetchAll($query);
    return $customAttributeValue[0]['value'];

}

?>
<style>
    tr td{
        border:1px solid black;
    }
</style>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>sku</td>
            <td>simple_skus</td>
            <td>type</td>
            <td>class</td>
            <td>silos</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
    foreach($parentCollection as $parentID){
        $parentProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($parentID->getId());
        $childProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')
                        ->getUsedProducts(null,$parentProducts);
        ?>

            <?php
            foreach($childProducts as $child){
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                <?php echo $child->getSku();?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo "&nbsp;"?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $child->getTypeId()?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php
                        $value =  $parentProducts->getClass();
                        echo getAttributeValue($value);
                        ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php
                        $value =  $parentProducts->getSilos();
                        echo getAttributeValue($value);
                        ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
              <?php }?>                    
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    <?php echo $parentProducts->getSku();                         
                    ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php
                        $separation = array();
                        foreach($childProducts as $child){
                        $separation[] = $child->getSku();
                        }
                        echo implode(',',$separation);
                        ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $parentProducts->getTypeId();?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php
                        $value =  $parentProducts->getClass();
                        echo getAttributeValue($value);
                        ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php
                        $value =  $parentProducts->getSilos();
                        echo getAttributeValue($value);
                        ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>         
        <?php
    }
    ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

then browser your filename.php from your website

from that list you can convert html to csv

check this 
http://www.convertcsv.com/html-table-to-csv.htm

hope this help

Answer (score 0):

Magento provides export and import for configurable products from System > Import/Export > Dataflow - Profiles, please see the attached image how it's exporting configurable products
[image: export configurable products]

Main columns to take care about are type and has option as parent product will be assigned with has_option as 1 ,visibility as catalog, seacrh and it's child products which will assigned value for has_option as 0 , visibililty as Not Visible Individually and it's related attributes values like shoe_type , shoe_size and gender

-magmi option to import configurable products which will assign Associated products to parent product.Before this import one need to first import simple and configurable products.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Really appreciate it. But as mentioned in my question, I am aware of this. Just to clear even further if you try to import this none of the configurable product of yours would have the linked simple products since in magento; export doesn't export the "ASSOCIATED" column and hence you loose the realtion.

Comment: Yes one need to manually assign Associated products to Parent one by editing it.

Comment: Exactly, so that was my point in the question, whether there is an alternative to this or not.

Comment: [magmi](http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/) may help I have edited my answer , hope this one helps

Comment: Yes, you are right..but that is also valid for magento import. The question was related to "EXPORT". BTW I am already using magmi, I just wanted to confirm about export (though I was partially aware ).